# How to tail a file over the network?

Tags: mount, tail

How can I `tail -f` a file that over the network, say at `\\192.168.2.130\public\print.log`?

I have tried the variations of the following:

- `tail -f //192.168.2.130/Southpaw/Tactic/print.log` which erred saying `` tail: cannot open `//192.168.2.130/Southpaw/Tactic/print.log' for reading: No such file or directory ``
- Mounted the path using the `mount -t cifs` and then tried `tail -f` but that isn't working either, meaning it doesn't output the updates that are made to the file.

Comment: What about if you do this over ssh? `ssh username@my.server.com "tail -f /var/log/example/print.log"` Is it an option to you to ssh to the other server? Since cifs is not a "panacea" to all file sharing issues, i would not trust it to export logfiles that require updates on-the-fly.

Comment: @nwildner The other server hosting the file is not Linux, but Windows. And I'm lazy enough to open it's remote-shell ;). Plus that seems more of an overkill.

Comment: Then, I  would suggest you the same as @jofel answer: Use watch to reload the last X lines of the file: `watch tail //192.168.2.130/Southpaw/Tactic/print.log` . The default is 2s on the watch command, and it can be changed with the `-n` parameter. :)

Answer (score 8):

Keep trying with mounted cifs. And just use tail with following parameter:

```
tail --retry --follow=name yourfile
```

Like this, tail follows the file name not the decriptor, and combined with `--retry` it tries again even if the file is inaccessible for some time.

Comment: Doesn't work. Not updating.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in the `cifs` kernel module. It could be that it is fixed in a newer kernel version than you use. Try the `directio` mount parameter to circumvent the bug (this could lower the filesystem perfomance heavily).

Using `watch tail print.log` could also be an solution. It displays the 10 last lines of the file every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The smb protocol is archaic with a bunch of added on extensions. It was not designed to handle your workflow, and no one has added support for it. either use a hack like the --follow=name in gnu tail or a different protocol. I would be inclined to do the tail on the server and use netcat for network transport, unless the server is windows, in which case I would do some testing, or try to find another server.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `cache=none` parameter helped.

I mount Windows share using this command:

```
sudo mount.cifs //IP_ADDRES/logs3 /tmp/logs3 -o user=user,password=pass,ro,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,cache=none
```